# Default permission for /opt/lampp folder

Tags: 14.04, permissions, lamp

I want to know correct permission or default permission for `/opt/lampp` folder. By mistake I have given command `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp`. Therefore I am getting error.

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). 
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I tried:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp
```

but it's not working.

Comment: `/opt/` means you installed from source? The permissions of the files are not 1 set (ie. all 755 or all 644) and will have different permissions. You could try to set all dirs to 755 and all files to 644 but probably need to delete `/opt/lampp/` and re-install the source files.

Comment: I concur to Rinzwind's comment, but I'd like to see an explicit statement about how you installed LAMPP. This will considerably influence the concrete solution.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind and David Foerster for comments. I set sudo chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp and restart lampp server. It works fine.Thanks Shahab [website](http://hrms-systems.com)